# EXCEL VBA: Column auto-fills even after specifying not to if input column is empty

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and this is my third code. It is a simple code which calculates when the next birthdate should be once I input the initial date of birth and also lets me know how many days are left before I need to make the necessary birthday preparations :)

I will try to provide as much information as possible so please don't get intimidated by this wall of text. Also, since I just started learning a few days back I wrote the code with the limited amount o

Any ways this is the code that I came up with:

```
Sub Next_Birthday()

Dim Birthdate As Date
Dim nr As Long
Dim Today As Date
Dim Nextbdate As Date
Dim NoDays As Long

For nr = 2 To 20000

Birthdate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(nr, "B")
Today = Date

Nextbdate = DateSerial(Year(Today), Month(Birthdate), Day(Birthdate))

If Nextbdate >= Today Then
    Nextbdate = DateSerial(Year(Today), Month(Birthdate), Day(Birthdate))
Else
 Nextbdate = DateSerial(Year(Today) + 1, Month(Birthdate), Day(Birthdate))
End If

If Cells(nr, "A") = "" Then
    Cells(nr, "C") = "" & Cells(nr, "D") = ""
Else
    Cells(nr, "C").Value = Nextbdate
    Cells(nr, "D").Value = (Nextbdate - Today)
End If

Next
End Sub
```

This is what my excel looks like once I play the code:
[image]
When I hit play, though I get the desired results but it autofills the remaining of column C with the value of TRUE. If you see the last part of my code I had specifically asked excel to not fill my columns if there are no values in Column A.

Thank you for your time and I would really appreciate any suggestions tips to help solve that small issue. Also feel free to ask if you need more information.

Regards,
InWoods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `Cells(nr, "C") = "" & Cells(nr, "D") = ""` to

```
Cells(nr, "C") = "" 
 Cells(nr, "D") = ""
```

the `&` and `=` in your line forces it to evaluate.

Comment: That was so fast! Thank you! It works perfectly now :) I don't know how that slipped my mind.

Comment: Thank you for your time and input @cyboashu you are awesome :D

Comment: you are welcome. :)  And mark the question as answered.

Comment: yes it is currently on cooldown as the website didn;t expect such a quick answer. Will do it in 3 mins :) ty

Comment: @ YowE3K: Removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very easily without VBA by the following formulas in C2 and D2, then drag down.

C2:`=IF(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))>=TODAY(),DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(B2),DAY(B2)),DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+1,MONTH(B2),DAY(B2)))`

D2: `=C2-TODAY()`

If you really need VBA, the code can be refactored to the below to work as you like:

```
Sub Next_Birthday()

Dim Birthdate As Date
Dim nr As Long
Dim Today As Date
Dim Nextbdate As Date
Dim NoDays As Long
Dim rName As Range

Today = Date

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each rName In .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown))

        Birthdate = rName.Offset(, 1)
        Nextbdate = DateSerial(Year(Today), Month(Birthdate), Day(Birthdate))

        If Nextbdate >= Today Then
            Nextbdate = DateSerial(Year(Today), Month(Birthdate), Day(Birthdate))
        Else
            Nextbdate = DateSerial(Year(Today) + 1, Month(Birthdate), Day(Birthdate))
        End If

        rName.Offset(, 2) = Nextbdate
        rName.Offset(, 3) = (Nextbdate - Today)

    Next

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your time :) I will try to experiment with the code you gave me :D It's always fun to see every one looks and solves the same problem so uniquely :D ty